# Input number with 01 value to toString in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using input type number in my html. In javascript/jquery I need to check the length of digits and I am using `toString().length`. But it converts **01** to **1** and length becomes `1`. Instead it should print `2` as length.

```
<input id="exp-mm" maxlength="2" type="number">
```

Comment: 01 is not a number. If you want that format you need to use `type="text"`.

Comment: User is only allowed to enter digits.

Comment: Then you have to add custom validation. It's `type="number"`, not `type="digits"`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, for this use case, you can't use `type="number"` because you want `01` to not change to `1`. Use `type="text"` and you can have an `onChange` event to enforce only digits using a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of what you're trying to do based on the [form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) docs on MDN.

https://jsfiddle.net/xbq3tf3t/1/

HTML:

```
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation -->

<form>
  <label for="month">Expiry month (mm)</label>
  <input id="month" required pattern="0?[1-9]|1[0-2]">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<div>
Length: <span id="length"></span>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('month')
  .addEventListener('keyup', event => {
    const element = document.getElementById('length');
    element.innerText = event.target.value.length;
  });
```

CSS:

```
input:invalid {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

input:valid {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to check how many letters/numbers are there in your input field, you can check this way

```
document.getElementById("exp-mm").value.split("").length
```

```js
var e = document.getElementById("exp-mm");

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){

  console.log(e.value.length)
})
```

```html
<input id="exp-mm" maxlength="2" type="number">
<button id="btn">Count</button>
```